# Issue in connection pool startup with hikaricp, jdbctemplate, spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

I am using hikari with spring jdbctemplate in spring boot application.
My database connection pool is not starting up after application startup.
The connection pool is started only after first call to DB, which results into my first service call.
Any suggestion how to initialize connection pool on boot application start up..?

Comment: Put some code in question so that we help!(.yml and java class code) and also tell which spring boot version you are using

Comment: Update your question with the little effort in code perspective

Answer (score 5):

Lazy-init property of JdbcTemplate is set by default to true. So only the first access to it will setup your connection pool.

You can override this behavior in this way :

`@Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource)
    {
     return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource, false);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone, i got it fixed 
Inside my initDatasource method -
first - i created HikariConfig hikariDSObject = new HikariConfig();
then i set all properties 
At last - i pass hikariDSObject in to HikariDataSource object.

it helps to initialize connection pool at startup